# Scraping CSV data from BasketballReference

Tags: javascript, csv, web-scraping

I want to scrape seasonal NBA team data from basketball-reference.com in CSV format. There is an option to convert these tables into CSV, but it requires clicking on a `span` with an `onclick` handler. [This is an example.](http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2015.html#all_team_stats)

Is there a way (don't really care what language) that I can write a scraper where it first somehow triggers each of these spans and then scrapes the CSV data?

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out today. What I really want from this are the "player ID" values that you see when tables throughout the site are displayed as CSV. For example, `Steven Adams\adamsst01,2014,2019,C,7-0,265,July 20 1993,Pitt`. Can't seem to access that version of the data using the rvest package.

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't care about the language, you can try [WatIn](http://watin.org/). I've already use it for test automation purpouse, but in your case, should work also (thinking in some clicks in `span`).

[Tutorial how to use WatIn](http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/automated-web-testing-1-using-watin)

Comment: Hmmm... looks interesting. I'll take a look! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late, but perhaps of benefit to those coming here via search: it is possible to get nice CSV data from basketball-reference.com. It's not obvious (and maybe what follows wasn't possible a year-and-a-half ago), but try this:

At the top of the table are some links like

> Glossary  · SHARE  · Embed  · CSV  · Export  · PRE  · LINK  · ?

Click on the SHARE link (*not* the CSV link)
This will bring up a similar table, where, if you wish, you can exclude some data from the CSV.
In the yellow box should be some links like

> Share or get code for table as:
>   html  / link url / bbcode [table] or [code] / js  widget / > / pre-formatted text / comma-separated / [[wiki]]

Click on 'comma-separated'.
An overlay should pop-up with the CSV data, which you can copy-and-paste.

Comment: I understand the op wanted to automatically get the csv data without copy/pasting... at least that's what I was looking for when landing here.